# usando sortable dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sortable

toda vez que eu arrastar e "dropar" a barra de `input` do tipo `text` dentro dos botões, deve-se gerar a mesma barra de input abaixo do **cabeçalho** menu .

**Problema:**

Toda vez que eu dropo o input dentro dos botões, este mesmo input some e não gerado um novo. como implementar essa parte?

```
  <h2> Menu </h2>
  <div id="menu" class="connectedSortable"></div>

  <h2> Botoes </h2>
  <div id="tbody-content" class="connectedSortable"></div>
```

## sortable

```
$("#menu").append(appendMenu());

$('#tbody-content').sortable({ items: 'ul' });
$( "#menu" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

No [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbdnew6g/11/)

Comment: Eu não consegui entender o que está tentando fazer. O que quer dizer com dropar a barra de input dentro de um botão?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi seria adicionar uma nova caixa de texto na area dos botões realizando um "clone".

http://jsfiddle.net/bqe3t523/

```
$('#content').sortable({ 
    items: 'ul',
    revert: "invalid"
}).droppable();

$( "#menu" ).draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  connectToSortable: "#content"
}).disableSelection();
```